# How does matplotlib accept function parameters? Are they lambdas?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following syntax is very intuitive. Run in Spyder, and it plots a nonlinear function.

```
import numpy as numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

x = numpy.arange(0, 1, 0.01)

def nonlinear(x, deriv=False): #sigmoid
        if (deriv==True):
                return x*(1-x)

        return 1/(1-numpy.exp(-x))

plot.plot(x, nonlinear(x))
```

My question is, *how* is the function `nonlinear` passed to `plot.plot`? Is it a lambda? How is `nonlinear` accepting an array without crashing when it does math ops?

Comment: Sigmoid is `1/(1+exp(-x))`, by the way.

Comment: "how is the function nonlinear passed to plot.plot?" It is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine because the usual arithmetic operations (e.g. `/` and `-` as you've used) are defined for numpy arrays; they're just performed element-wise. The same goes for `np.exp()`. You can see exactly what `nonlinear(x)` looks like for yourself (it's also a numpy array):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def nonlinear(x): return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))
... 
>>> nonlinear(np.arange(0, 1, 0.1))
array([ 0.5       ,  0.52497919,  0.549834  ,  0.57444252,  0.59868766,
        0.62245933,  0.64565631,  0.66818777,  0.68997448,  0.7109495 ])
```

You're just finding the value of the sigmoid evaluated at each point in the specified range, and passing those as the y-values to `plot`.

Answer (score 1):

Python has special double underscore methods. e.g. `__add__`, `__sub__`, etc. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html has a more comprehensive list.

x + y is just `x.__add__(y)`
x * y is just `x.__mul__(y)`

Numpy makes use of these "magic" methods to implement point-wise arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

The matplotlib `plot` function needs two lists (or numpy arrays) as arguments for x and y. As arshajii answered the syntax is vaild because the numpy array `x` is evaluated elementwise in the return statement of the `nonlinear` function (which is really nice).

However, in case the nonlinear function includes a case-by-case operation a numpy evaluation is not possible anymore (without some further numpy-magic). For example look at this continuously differentiable but non-smooth function:

```
from pylab import *

def nonlinear(x, x0=2):
        return x**2 if x < x0 else 2*x0*(x - x0) + x0**2

x = linspace(0, 5, 100)
y = nonlinear(x)
```

The last line rises the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Instead use a list comprehension

```
y = [nonlinear(x_, x0=2.5) for x_ in x]
plot(x, y)
show()
```

which results in the following figure
[image: non-smooth function]